# Why moving_mean and moving_variance not in tf.trainable_variables()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using `tf.layers.batch_normalization(a_pl, training=True)`.
By `tf.trainable_variables()`, I can see all trainable variables. But I cannot find `moving_mean` and `moving_variances` in them.

Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
a_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 3])
b = tf.layers.batch_normalization(a_pl, training=True)
vl = [var.name for var in tf.trainable_variables()]
for v in vl:
    print v
```

Here's outputs:

```
batch_normalization/gamma:0
batch_normalization/beta:0
```

I'm wondering why `moving_mean` and `moving_variances` are not included in `tf.trainable_variables()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trainable variables are trained using gradient descent. The batch normalization moving mean and variances aren't trained using gradient descent, but computed directly from activations that pass through the network, so they should not be included as trainable variables.

So in a way you can say they are automatically trained, but not with gradient descent, so they are not trainable variables in that sense.